# Single Source File Reference on Eclipse Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse and I have two projects (say A and B) written in Java. In project-A I want to add a reference to a single source file of project-B. When I build a jar from project-A, I want that class to be included in it. Is there a way to achieve this?

I want to add reference to a single source file so the following method does not work for me since it gives reference to a complete folder:

```
Java Build Path -> Source -> Link Source
```

Comment: The second window of `Link Source` wizard is to ask you include/exclude source, just include the sinlge souce file you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Ok.... let me put it this way.........

When we don't use the `import` keyword, then we need to write the entire path of that class that we are trying to use in the code...

So its like this....

```
java.util.List<String> l = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
```

that means we are giving the **package name and then its class**........

So then there are **2 ways you can deal with it :**

**- Add** the `whole package` into the `project path`.

**-** Or you can `Copy-Paste` **that class** into your project.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a valid explanation since package name is declared in individual source files.

Comment: @paritybit having `package line in every source file without the existence of that package will give you an ERROR.....`

Comment: does this mean you have a package definition independent of the declerations on source files? if so where are these definitions?